# Not able to reduce the height of rows of table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried different method to reduce the height of the row of  table but i am not able to do that  this is my code can anyone help me to do it

```
<table  class="table table-bordered" style=" width:750px; table-layout:fixed ; margin-bottom:50px;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px 1px;border: 1px solid black;"  >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr >
                                            <th width="50px" >Sl.No.</th>
                                            <th style="display:none;" >Txn ID.</th>
                                            <th width="175px">Stationery Type</th>
                                            <th width="73px">Purpose</th>
                                            <th width="84px">Quantity Requested</th>    
                                            <th width="65px">Balance</th>                                           
                                            <th width="78px">Quantity Issued</th>
                                            <th>Remarks</th>
                                                                                    
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                 
                                    <tbody>
                                    
    
                <tr style="height:2px;" >
                                           
                                            <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
                                            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationerytype);?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->purpose);?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?></td>
                                            <td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyrqst" style="border: 1px solid #206020; border-radius: 4px;background:#b4e3cf;;" max="<?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?>" > </td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="remarks" style="border: 1px solid #206020; border-radius: 4px;background:#b4e3cf;;"  > </td>
                 </tr>
                                        
                                         <?php $cnt++;} ?>
                                         <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. change all the `<td>` height
2. make a style/css `td { height: 20px }`

Comment: It is not changing the height

Answer (score 0):

You can not reduce your row height lower than its content.

Please refer to the

```css
.table-row{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}


.table-row-2{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 4px; //won't work
  height: 12px;// will work
}
```

```html
<table  class="table table-bordered" style=" width:750px; table-layout:fixed ; margin-bottom:50px;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px 1px;border: 1px solid black;"  >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="50px" >Sl.No.</th>
    <th style="display:none;" >Txn ID.</th>
    <th width="175px">Stationery Type</th>
    <th width="73px">Purpose</th>
    <th width="84px">Quantity Requested</th>    
    <th width="65px">Balance</th>                                           
    <th width="78px">Quantity Issued</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
   <tr>
   <tr class="table-row-2">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
   <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

below snippet.

Comment: I think my row height is not reducing though it is increasing by <tr style="line-height:3.14;" > .I dont know how it happened

Comment: your tr height will increase if you set height attribute as well. line-height is basically **height = line-height*font-size**. So it will leave an equal amount of space at the top and bottom of the content and no need to specify the height explicitly when font size changes on a different viewport. Also, it is useful to separate the lines when you have multiple lines. It guarantee a minimum space between two lines.

Comment: I tried after removing all the height  but still it was same

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line-height of the row.

```
<tr style="line-height:3.14;" >
  <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
  <td style="display:none;"><?php echo htmlentities($result->txnid);?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationerytype);?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->purpose);?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyrqst" style="border: 1px solid #206020; border-radius: 4px;background:#b4e3cf;" 
      max="<?php echo htmlentities($result->stationeryqtyrqst);?>" > </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="remarks" style="border: 1px solid #206020; border-radius: 4px;background:#b4e3cf;"  > </td>
</tr>
```